# Check next group where specified column is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have an approval flow which is grouped by `Action` (Requestor, Verifier and Approver). The logic is when one of the verifiers have taken action (`ActionDate` has value), it will display the users from the next group. Meaning, the `Verifier` group has already verified `RequestNo` R001 and the request should now be pending to Approver group. What I need is to display the next Action (Approver) and the users.

`Approval` table

```
RequestNo | UserName | Action    | Seq | ActionDate
R001      | JohnD    | Requestor | 1   | 01/01/2017
R001      | SamS     | Verifier  | 2   | NULL
R001      | TrishL   | Verifier  | 3   | 01/01/2017
R001      | GeorgeP  | Verifier  | 4   | NULL
R001      | JackF    | Approver  | 5   | NULL
R001      | RobertL  | Approver  | 6   | NULL
```

Comment: What does your query look like so far, and what error are you getting?

Comment: What is is your input data and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Using a correlated subquery to only return those rows where the `Action` is equal to the "Next" action group (based on `seq`), eliminating those groups that have a non-null `ActionDate` with `not exists()`

```
select ap.*
from Approval ap 
where ap.Action = (
    select top 1 ac.Action 
    from Approval ac
    where not exists (
      select 1
      from Approval i
      where i.RequestNo = ap.RequestNo
        and i.Action = ac.Action
        and i.ActionDate is not null
      )
    order by ac.seq asc
    )
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/UPCZO55513

returns:

```
+-----------+----------+----------+-----+------------+
| RequestNo | UserName |  Action  | Seq | ActionDate |
+-----------+----------+----------+-----+------------+
| R001      | JackF    | Approver |   5 | NULL       |
| R001      | RobertL  | Approver |   6 | NULL       |
+-----------+----------+----------+-----+------------+
```

Comment: I put `AND RequestNo = 'R001'` inside the `select 1 from Approval i` WHERE statement but it took sql server too long to generate the result and it did not display the correct RequestNo

Comment: @HarambeAttackHelicopter  Have you been able to find a workable solution?  I am confident my answer below will do what you require.

Comment: @HarambeAttackHelicopter you should put that in the outermost part of the query. `and ap.RequestNo='R001'`

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with a derived table and some window functions which, in my opinion at least is a bit easier to read and understand than several sub-queries on top of one another:

```
declare @Approval table(RequestNo nvarchar(10),UserName nvarchar(10),Action nvarchar(10),Seq int,ActionDate date);
insert into @Approval values ('R001','JohnD','Requestor',1,'20170101'),('R001','SamS','Verifier',2,NULL),('R001','TrishL','Verifier',3,'20170102'),('R001','GeorgeP','Verifier',4,NULL),('R001','JackF','Approver',5,NULL),('R001','RobertL','Approver',6,NULL);

with c as
(
    select RequestNo
            ,min(Seq) as MinSeq
            ,max(Seq) as MaxSeq
            ,row_number() over (partition by RequestNo order by RequestNo, min(ActionDate), min(Seq)) as rn
    from @Approval
    group by RequestNo
            ,Action
)
select a.*
from @Approval a
    join c
        on(a.RequestNo = c.RequestNo
            and a.Seq between c.MinSeq and c.MaxSeq
            and c.rn = 1
            )
order by a.RequestNo
        ,a.Seq;
```

Output:

```
+-----------+----------+----------+-----+------------+
| RequestNo | UserName |  Action  | Seq | ActionDate |
+-----------+----------+----------+-----+------------+
| R001      | JackF    | Approver |   5 | NULL       |
| R001      | RobertL  | Approver |   6 | NULL       |
+-----------+----------+----------+-----+------------+
```

---

Adding in additional data to show how it works on the entire set:

```
declare @Approval table(RequestNo nvarchar(10),UserName nvarchar(10),Action nvarchar(10),Seq int,ActionDate date);
insert into @Approval values
 ('R001','JohnD','Requestor',1,'20170101'),('R001','SamS','Verifier',2,NULL),('R001','TrishL','Verifier',3,'20170102'),('R001','GeorgeP','Verifier',4,NULL),('R001','JackF','Approver',5,NULL),('R001','RobertL','Approver',6,NULL)
,('R002','JohnD','Requestor',1,'20170101'),('R002','SamS','Verifier',2,NULL),('R002','TrishL','Verifier',3,null),('R002','GeorgeP','Verifier',4,NULL),('R002','JackF','Approver',5,NULL),('R002','RobertL','Approver',6,NULL);
```

Output:

```
+-----------+----------+----------+-----+------------+
| RequestNo | UserName |  Action  | Seq | ActionDate |
+-----------+----------+----------+-----+------------+
| R001      | JackF    | Approver |   5 | NULL       |
| R001      | RobertL  | Approver |   6 | NULL       |
| R002      | SamS     | Verifier |   2 | NULL       |
| R002      | TrishL   | Verifier |   3 | NULL       |
| R002      | GeorgeP  | Verifier |   4 | NULL       |
+-----------+----------+----------+-----+------------+
```